# JavaScript event happens when scroll comes to the element without jQuery

Tags: javascript

I have some div with scroll.

I want to do with javascript, that function will active when the scroll of the div will comes to element.

I want to do this **without jQuery**.

How can I do it?

---

**example for source:**

*the div id=bb, is the element that when the scroll comes to, it will active the 'example' function*

```
<div id=aa>  // this div have scrollbar
     <br><br><br><Br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><Br><br><br><br><br>

     <div id=bb>this is the element that will active the function</div>

     <br><br><br><Br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><Br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
```

*this is the function that i want to active when the scroll comes to the element:*

```
function example() {
     document.write('work!');
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if element is visible after scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  var pos = window.pageYOffset;
  var b = getElementById("bb");
  var pos_bb = b.offset().top;
  if(pos == pos_show) {
      example();
  }          
}
```

try this, use pageYOffset;

Comment: I believe you want `pos == pos_bb` instead of `pos_show`. Also, this will only work if the scroll lines up exactly with the element, which might not happen.